# need to insert string of data into a table column with a NUMBER datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, I have a table with a column of data type NUMBER. I need to insert a string into a new row I'm about to create. The other rows can certainly remain NUMBERs because usually that's what I need to insert in them. So is there a way to insert a new row with a string sort of like this(this wouldn't work for me)?

```
INSERT INTO keyboard_learning (emplid,wpm,date_completed,exercise,attempt)
VALUES (seq_keyboard_learning.nextval,to_char('LEVEL 3'),'14-JUN-2012','Meteor typing blast',1)
```

I want to create a new row where usually I would put a number like for example ' 23 ' in a new row of the WPM column. This time I want to put 'LEVEL 3'instead just the number 23

Comment: please explain what you mean: you don't insert into a row but into a field. Which field is it? Why do you need to insert a string into a number?

Comment: hi there. I want to create a new row where usually I would put a number like for example ' 23 ' in a new row of the WPM column. This time I want to put 'LEVEL 3'instead  just the number 23

Comment: Specify the column you are referring to, and please list the datatypes of the columns.

Comment: If the data in a column is sometimes numbers, sometimes not, you really need two distinct columns, one for the number, one for the string, or a single string (varchar) column.  You cannot put desserts in the slots on the menu reserved for main courses, or wines in the section of the menu reserved for the soup of the day.

Comment: Sure Tom, I apologize. The info is in my above comment

Comment: That makes sense Tim. I was wondering if I could typecast every now and then but it looks like I just have to have a separate column for sure then, right? Absolutely no way to typecast it?

Comment: You cannot insert a non-numeric value into a NUMERIC column. But you can insert a numeric value, in its string representation, into a varchar column.  If you have mixed data in the varchar column which sometimes could be cast as a number (e.g. "134.56") but at other times not ("DJM") then your casts would succeed sometimes and crash at others if a  mix of data was involved. You'd have to filter out/exclude the rows containing non-numeric data in order to have the cast work reliably. Fragile design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `WPM` is the `NUMBER` column that we're talking about, no, there is no way to insert a string like `"LEVEL 3"` into that column without changing the definition of the column.  You could convert the column to a `VARCHAR2` but that would cause numerous headaches down the line when you want to treat `WPM` like a number (i.e. have them sort numerically rather than alphabetically, compute percentage improvements, etc.).

Why do you want to store a string in a `WPM` column in the first place?  It seems likely that the problem is that you need a new column or, perhaps, a new entity in your data model.

Comment: Great answer Justin. Thank you so much. It's a dummy table i'm learning on. I'm tracking scores which typically are numbers but in this instance it was a level(string) instead of a score(number).

Comment: @Shades - But, since `"LEVEL 3"` is not a "words per minute" measure, why do you want to store it in the `WPM` column?  You almost certainly need to create an additional column or an additional entity to store information about levels.

Comment: some learning tools were games and did not provide a wpm, only a score. So I was going to use that in  place of the wpm this time. I will certainly make a new column called 'score' now.